# If 2 IEnumerable<T> contains the same item, is the item duplicated on memory?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, observablecollection

I need to get the Items form IListSource and add them to an ObservableCollection, would this duplicate the amount of memory or will the item just be referenced by the 2 IEnumerable?

```
public ObservableCollection<T> ObservableData { 
  get => _ObservableData; 
  set => _ObservableData = value; 
}

public void MoveToPage(int PageNumber) {
  this.CurrentPage = PageNumber;
  IEnumerable<T> InvokeData = ((IListSource)this).GetList().Cast<T>();

  foreach (var item in InvokeData) {
    this.ObservableData.Add(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the type of `T`. Is it a reference type, then the reference will be duplicated. Is it a value type, then the value will be duplicated. Have you tried creating a [mcve] and searching?

Comment: @CodeCaster You are right in general for regular types like lists and arrays that he is using. But IEnumerable is an abstraction and the you could have implementation that don't store all the values but calculate on the fly and do lazy loading. For example Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => random.Next()) will generate a different number every time you do a foreach.

Comment: @Filip yeah the title doesn't match the code.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes the question is unclear. He might be doing some linq queries like `var items = new object[1].Select(i => new object());` where you might not expect `items.First() == items.First()` to be false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word - no.

You have two references to the same object. The references themselves take memory, obviously, but you won't be doubling the memory required for the object.

Comment: As CodeCaster points out in a comment to the question, this is only true if `T` is a reference type, which is by no means guaranteed without further constraints expressed in the question.